# コメントになかなか返信がつきません

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案

投稿にコメントをもらったので返信コメントを打ったのですが、それに対する返信がなかなか来ません。何故でしょうか？

[←よくある質問の目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Overflowのコメント機能はコミュニケーションやディスカッションをする場ではありません。返信やお礼があることを期待しないでください。

コメントによって指摘や疑問の提示を受けた点は、コメントで返信するのではなく、該当する投稿を追記編集することで改善や補足してください。

質問に対して追加情報の提示を求められたがその調べ方がわからない、というような場合は、その点を新たに質問として投稿することもできます。

コメントの内容に対する単純な疑義であればコメントで返信してもかまいませんが、そのときは[返信先を指定](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328/)しないと相手に通知されません。